# Setting Triggers in Maria DB

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to set the trigger in maria db

The query which I am running is

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEMP
AFTER INSERT
    ON sample_details FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE SAMPLE_MONITOR SET TableDataCount= TableDataCount+ 1,Time=NOW() WHERE 
    TableName='sample_details';
END; //
delimiter ;
```

I have a table named 'sample_details' there If any insert is done to that table, I want to increment the count in the row present in SAMPLE_MONITOR table by 1 and also insert the current time

But I am getting the following error after running query

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

So anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a `delimiter //` statement before the trigger?

Comment: yes , something like this delimiter | , but I am doing it first time, don't know what is the delimiter thing does, as I referred online example

Comment: If you have `delimiter |`, then where you have `//` should instead be `|`.